# How to know the current UIViewController or a specific control (ios app)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Our project has been developed for 4 years. It contains tons of codes. Is there anyway to detect the name of the current UIViewController or a specific control when I run app and touch a specific control on the screen.

If there is no way, so I will dive in the code to debug. Sorry for my ignorance.

our code is written in objective-c, supports ios7,8,9,10, iphone and ipad

Comment: I do not think there is any way to identify current view controller or specific controls by just run and touch any control of the app. You need to add some code to identify current view controller or debug.

Comment: Thanks @shuvo. I think so.

Comment: Happy debugging. :-p

Answer (score 1):

While running, you can ask Xcode to freeze the screen and load its layout into Xcode.
It is called "Debug View Hierarchy"
[image]

In that view, you can right-click on elements and print their description into the lldb window. Also on the left you will see the full hierarchy of all the UI elements. Very useful for reverse engineering of code written by somebody else...

Comment: It's possibly an answer. I upvote your answer. I click on that button, but sometime, it said it's unable to capture the screen. Anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Ye I know, it is not always working. It is a big mystery when it does and when it doesn't. I was counting on your luck to succeed :). Please try both a real device and a simulator

Answer (score 0):

plz use this

```
 UIViewController *viewOb = [self getTopViewController];

     -(id)getTopViewController{


               UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

                while (topController.presentedViewController) {
                    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
                }
                if (![topController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

                    return topController;
                }



        }
```

Comment: it's not my question. Probably, you read too quickly. Thanks.

Comment: @chipbk10 you want current view controller name ? i am right.

Comment: I mean, your've just received a new project. You know nothing in code. Is it possible from the iPhone or iPad screen, when you touch or navigate to the new screen, you know which UIViewController you are currently in? Probably, there is no way. Thanks.

Comment: you have to write the code without this i think it's not possible .